# All PhoneGap 3.5 oAuth Attempts Fail (iOS)

Tags: cordova, webview

I am attempting to achieve oAuth authentication within a PhoneGap app for iOS. I am running into the following issue. I have been primarily testing this for Google oAuth but have tried LinkedIn as well with similar results:

1. I am able to launch the InAppBrowser, log in to my Google account and authorize the app to access to my account.
2. The InAppBrowser successfully returns an access token, expiry, etc. When the app then tries to send the access token back, I get the following error in XCode:

> webView:didFailLoadWithError - -1004: Could not connect to the server.

This occurs when I run the app on **either** the iOS simulator OR an actual iPhone.

What I have tried:

- Trying multiple different code samples, including what oauth.io provides as a code sample for their service.
- Installing Xcode on a separate computer and trying there.
- Trying an older version of PhoneGap

Interestingly, this occurs when I have the "redirect URI" set to:

```
http://localhost
```

.. as defined by the Google API Console, and by all of the OAuth implementation tutorials I've gone through. Apparently the InAppBrowser code is supposed to stop the page from loading and grab the data that is appended to the URL string. If I swap the redirect for the other value that Google's console provides (urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob), it redirects to an actual page with instruction to copy and paste code from an input to my URL bar. Which doesn't help me in the context of the InAppBrowser.

I am at a loss for what to try next. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried OAuth tools like [OAuth.io](https://oauth.io) ?

There's a Phonegap/Cordova SDK that allows you to use OAuth an perform API calls with much less pain.

Once you've created an account, you can find guides for the Phonegap SDK there:

- https://oauth.io/getting-started?phonegap&None

And the docs here:

- https://oauth.io/docs/api-reference/client/phonegap

And a step by step tutorial about a typical project there:

- https://oauth.io/docs/tutorials/client/phonegap

OAuth.io is a Saas solution. If you're more interested in an open source solution, you can check out [oauthd](https://github.com/oauth-io/oauthd), the open sourced version of the core.

Hope that helps :)